# Getting value of an element inside facebox div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two div tags as shown below on my page. When i reference the value of itemName element,using **$('#itemName').val();** which i have in both the divs, i always get the value of the element in the first div which is ""(blank). Is there a way to get the value of the itemName element in the 2nd div i.e. facebox using jquery ?

info div

```
<div id="info" style="display: none;">
<center>
<strong>Name</strong>
<input id="itemName" type="text"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<strong>Price  </strong>
<input id="itemPrice" type="text"/>
<br/>
<br/>
</center>
</div>
```

facebox div

```
<div id="facebox" style="top: 27.3px; left: 478px; display: none;">
<div class="popup">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="b"/>
<td class="body">
<div class="content" style="display: block;">
<div id="info" style="">
<center>
<strong>Name</strong>
<input id="itemName" type="text"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<strong>Price  </strong>
<input id="itemPrice" type="text"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="button" onclick="updateTab();" value="Add"/>
</center>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

If you look inside facebox.js, you'll see that there is an event that is triggered when facebox opens, so you just need to bind to that event, then obtain the value:

```
$(document).bind('reveal.facebox', function() { 
 $('#facebox #itemName').val();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

An element id must be unique within a document. Your document is invalid and this is one of the consequences.

Make use of a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/), it is a cheap form of QA that makes it easy to grab some low hanging fruit.

Comment: A validator won't catch this as the facebox content is dynamically created from the content you select. It might just be better to use classes instead of IDs. But I think his real problem is getting the data from the facebox after it has been revealed - which is what my answer addresses.

Answer (score 1):

IDs have to be unique on the page - the simple answer is you need to rename one of them.

If you really can't change them then you could use something like this:

```
$('#facebox input[type=text]:first').val();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Greg. The problem is the 2nd div is generated using the facebox plugin,and the 1st div is what it uses to generate that.